# Why doesn't useSelector doesn't re-execute JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am making an app which should load content from api and immediately display components based on that data. Firstly, when it fetches the data, it should dispatch it to redux store and then with useSelector should trigger the change and pass the value as a prop to children component. Problem is that it does dispatch and select it with selector (there are console logs in code to confirm) but in doesn't pass it to child via props. I know that I can use useSelector in child but I am now intrested why doesn't it work this way.

Component 1

```js
    const Menu = () => {
      console.log("reload");
      const food = useSelector((state) => state.foodList.food);
      console.log(food);
      const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState(food);
      // console.log(foodList);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const page = useSelector((state) => state.ui.page);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const getFoodList = async () => {
          const response = await fetch(
            "https://senbonzakura-food-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/food.json"
          );
          if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
          const data = await response.json();
          const foodList = data[Object.keys(data)[0]];
          console.log("---");
          console.log(foodList);
          console.log("---");
          dispatch(foodSliceActions.updateFoodList(foodList));
        };
    
        try {
          getFoodList();
          // dispatch(foodSliceActions.updateFoodList(foodList));
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }, []);
      // const navigate = useNavigate();
    
      // const queryPrams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
      // const sort = queryPrams.get("sort");
    
      return (
        <main className={classes["menu-main"]}>
          <section
            className={`${classes["menu__section"]} ${classes["menu__left-side"]}`}
          >
            <div className={classes["menu__label"]}>
              <h1>MENU</h1>
              <h1>{page + 1}</h1>
            </div>
            <MenuList foodList={foodList ? foodList : []} page={page} />
          </section>
          <section
            className={`${classes["menu__section"]} ${classes["menu__right-side"]}`}
          >
            <Outlet />
          </section>
        </main>
      );
    };
    
    export default Menu;
```

Child component

```js
const formatArray = (array) => {
  const pages = Math.ceil(array.length / 5);

  const arr = [];
  let helpArr = [];

  let c = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
    for (let j = c; j < c + 5; j++) {
      helpArr.push(array[j]);
    }
    c += 5;
    arr.push(helpArr);
    helpArr = [];
  }

  return arr;
};

const MenuList = (props) => {
  const page = props.page;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const DUMMY_FOOD = props.foodList;
  console.log(DUMMY_FOOD);

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();
  const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFoodList(formatArray(DUMMY_FOOD));
  }, []);

  const queryPrams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const sort = queryPrams.get("sort");

  const onNextPageHandler = () => {
    dispatch(uiSliceActions.updatePage("forward"));
  };
  const onPreviousPageHandler = () => {
    dispatch(uiSliceActions.updatePage("backward"));
  };
  const onSortPageHandler = () => {
    navigate(`/menu/${params.foodId}/?sort=${sort === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"}`);
    sort === "asc"
      ? (DUMMY_FOOD = DUMMY_FOOD.sort((a, b) => a.foodPrice - b.foodPrice))
      : (DUMMY_FOOD = DUMMY_FOOD.sort((a, b) => b.foodPrice - a.foodPrice));
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className={classes["menu-list"]}>
        {foodList[page]
          ? foodList[page].map((foodObj) => (
              <MenuItem key={foodObj.id} foodObj={foodObj} />
            ))
          : ""}
      </div>
      <div className={classes["menu-list__buttons"]}>
        {page >= 1 && (
          <Button type="button" onClick={onPreviousPageHandler}>
            Page {page}
          </Button>
        )}
        <Button type="button" onClick={onSortPageHandler}>
          {sort === "asc" ? `Descending` : `Ascending`}
        </Button>
        <Button type="button" onClick={onNextPageHandler}>
          Page {page + 2}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default MenuList;
```

food-slice

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = { food: [] };

const foodSlice = createSlice({
  name: "foodList",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateFoodList(state, action) {
      //   console.log(action.payload);
      state.food = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

const foodSliceActions = foodSlice.actions;

export const foodSliceReducer = foodSlice.reducer;
export default foodSliceActions;
```

index (store)

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { uiSliceReducer } from "./ui-slice";
import { cartSliceReducers } from "./cart-slice";
import { foodSliceReducer } from "./food-slice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    ui: uiSliceReducer,
    cart: cartSliceReducers,
    foodList: foodSliceReducer,
  },
});

export default store;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just to make it clear, `console.log(DUMMY_FOOD);` logs the same array over and over again, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the following code in component1

```
const food = useSelector((state) => state.foodList.food);
const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState(food);
```

Here, you set food as initial state value of foodList state, so foodList is updated as food only when the component1 loads initially (componentDidMount lifecycle), instead of updating whenever food is updated.
If you wants to update foodList whenever food is updated, you need to set it in useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => { setFoodList(food) }, [food]);
```

Btw, you don't need to pass food as props to the child component.
You can use food directly in child component.
I updated your code.

component1

```
const Menu = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const page = useSelector((state) => state.ui.page);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getFoodList = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://senbonzakura-food-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/food.json"
      );
      if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
      const data = await response.json();
      const foodList = data[Object.keys(data)[0]];
      dispatch(foodSliceActions.updateFoodList(foodList));
    };

    try {
      getFoodList();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className={classes["menu-main"]}>
      <section
        className={`${classes["menu__section"]} ${classes["menu__left-side"]}`}
      >
        <div className={classes["menu__label"]}>
          <h1>MENU</h1>
          <h1>{page + 1}</h1>
        </div>
        <MenuList page={page} />
      </section>
      <section
        className={`${classes["menu__section"]} ${classes["menu__right-side"]}`}
      >
        <Outlet />
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

child component

```
const formatArray = (array) => {
  const pages = Math.ceil(array.length / 5);

  const arr = [];
  let helpArr = [];

  let c = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
    for (let j = c; j < c + 5; j++) {
      helpArr.push(array[j]);
    }
    c += 5;
    arr.push(helpArr);
    helpArr = [];
  }

  return arr;
};

const MenuList = (props) => {
  const page = props.page;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const DUMMY_FOOD = useSelector((state) => state.foodList.food);
  const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();

  const queryPrams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const sort = queryPrams.get("sort");

  useEffect(() => {
    setFoodList(DUMMY_FOOD);
  }, [DUMMY_FOOD]);

  const onNextPageHandler = () => {
    dispatch(uiSliceActions.updatePage("forward"));
  };
  const onPreviousPageHandler = () => {
    dispatch(uiSliceActions.updatePage("backward"));
  };
  const onSortPageHandler = () => {
    navigate(`/menu/${params.foodId}/?sort=${sort === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"}`);
    sort === "asc"
      ? (setFoodList(foodList.sort((a, b) => a.foodPrice - b.foodPrice)))
      : (setFoodList(foodList.sort((a, b) => b.foodPrice - a.foodPrice)));
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className={classes["menu-list"]}>
        {foodList[page]
          ? foodList[page].map((foodObj) => (
              <MenuItem key={foodObj.id} foodObj={foodObj} />
            ))
          : ""}
      </div>
      <div className={classes["menu-list__buttons"]}>
        {page >= 1 && (
          <Button type="button" onClick={onPreviousPageHandler}>
            Page {page}
          </Button>
        )}
        <Button type="button" onClick={onSortPageHandler}>
          {sort === "asc" ? `Descending` : `Ascending`}
        </Button>
        <Button type="button" onClick={onNextPageHandler}>
          Page {page + 2}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default MenuList;
```